# Pronunciation of -phemism

Tags: pronunciation

I know how to pronounce [euphemism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/euphemism), which I ask NOT about. Yet I only encountered its antonym [dysphemism](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dysphemism) today. Though I still don`t understand phonetic symbols (see [here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/11718/5306)), am I right that the root *-phemism* must be pronounced identically in both words? I see that the prefixes differ.

If so, is ODO's audible pronunciation clip wrong? I hear an additional NUH sound between `fe` and `mism`, which I would try to transcribe as: 
diss-`phe`-NUH-`mism`.

Footnote: I'm using Firefox and tried to link to that pronunciation clip for your convenience, but I can't extract a link. Please advise or edit this if you can.

Comment: You hear it correctly, and it is spoken incorrectly.

Comment: *PH* in English is almost *always* pronounced as the English pronounce *F*, though the language is somewhat ha*ph*azard. *Phenolphthalein* is a good test for the pH.

Comment: (Native AmE) I also hear the ODO's British pronunciation of _dysphemism_ as dĭs'-fĭn''-ə-mĭz''-m, which is wrong and doesn't match the indicated pronunciation. Good job spotting the error! I see that TRomano has already reported it to them.

Comment: @BenKovitz Thank you for your continuously helpful input! I didn't realise that you could report errors to the ODO; I would've if I had known, but I'm happy that user TRomano did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. There seems to be some mistake in ODO's audio clip. However, the phonetic symbols have been listed down correct.

> Euphemism : /ˈjuː**fəmɪz(ə)m**/
>   Dysphemism : /ˈdɪs**fɪmɪz(ə)m**/

For the correct pronunciation, you can refer to [this](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dysphemism) link

Comment: It appears that ODO has now corrected the pronunciation.